# rails ajax form cancel link get rid of form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, unobtrusive-javascript

If im using Ajax to render a form into a DOM element on my page, how would I handle cancel link  behavior?

Assuming I have <%= f.submit %> at the bottom of the form, what would I use for a cancel link next to it?

The ideal would be to get rid of the form without submitting or redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whatever you prefer.

```
= link_to 'Cancel', '#', class: 'cancel-link'
```

or

```
= button_to 'Cancel', '#', class: 'cancel-link'
```